# AngularJS Bug? - Select Multiple - Dynamically set size dependent on number of options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I want to dynamically control the size of a multi-select.

html

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="formData.selected_tests" 
    ng-options="c.test for c in tests"
    multiple="true"
    ng-multiple="true"
    name="tests"
    id="tests"
    size="{{ tests.length }}"
    ng-size="{{ tests.length }}">
</select>
```

js

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/test' })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.tests = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

Output from inspect element

```
<select 
    class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty" 
    ng-model="formData.selected_tests" 
    ng-options="c.test for c in tests" 
    multiple="true" 
    ng-multiple="true" 
    name="tests" 
    id="tests" 
    size="0" 
    ng-size="7">
        ... Options ...
</select>
```

Notice how `size` attribute remains at 0, however ng-size changes to 7 despite the same interpolated `tests.length` being used.

Further, despite there being a total of 7 options, the browser rendered size only displays 4 options.

Manually changing `size="0"` to `size="7"` within google chrome's element inspector, changes the size of the select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had some problems with `@size`. Try `ng-attr-size`, as:

```
<select
    ...
    ng-attr-size="{{ tests.length }}">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Is that in the docs??? I didn't even know that existed... will accept answer as soon as able to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is `data-ng-attr-size="{{ tests.length }}"`.

The [github issue 1619](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1619) describes this problem. It seems to be solved since  *angularjs* 1.1.4 in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cf17c6af475eace31cf52944afd8e10d3afcf6c0). There's an example for usage [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a1xLPGn2YeW0WavH2auD?p=preview).